# AngularJS object serialisation shortcoming

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, angularjs, mongoose

I am doing an angularJS application served by a node.js/mongodb backend.

My server supply a rest API that store and return JSON object. Some of my mongodb schema have several ref that are populated on the fly before being served to the angularJS application. Some of my object are "complex", i.e. I've got an object which contains an array of objects, these objects have got a reference to my user. It seems that when I am using a $resource to update (PUT) this object on the server, the last level of indirection is not processed.

instead of :

```
{
    enrollments: [
       {
           price: 100,
           userProfile: {
               _id: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'
               name: "Roger"
           }
       }
    ]
}
```

I've got something like that :

```
{
    enrollments: [
       {
           price: 100,
           userProfile: [Object]
       }
    ]
}
```

And so my update erase the information about the user profile in my database. Seems that after the third level the serializer stops looking for more data.

I've done some extensive research in the AngularJS documentation, on stackoverflow but to no avail. Certainly because of the generic nature of this problem.

My current conclusion would be to write a custom "request transformation" to change the way the JSON is serialized. But it is needed ? Is there a simpler way to solve this problem ?

Thanks,
Stéphane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems what you have in the DB doesn't correspond to what you have in the Mongoose schema. Have you changed the schema in mongoose after already having some existing data? This happened to me last week so it's my first guess...

Also can you confirm that this is due to Angular.js? For example can you try to debug your node.js app and see if it works fine? This doesn't sound like a client-side issue at all!

**UPDATE**:

Can you confirm that when posting/getting data with some HTTP client (e.g. [Postman REST Client](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman-rest-client/fdmmgilgnpjigdojojpjoooidkmcomcm?hl=en)) the API works just fine.

Comment: Not that I remember of. 

The data are correctly processed on the server side, only when they are coming back from angular they are mangled.

Comment: can you post your Mongoose schema (at least part of it that gets messed up) and few data examples?

Comment: You know the moment you say you checked and then you think, I will check again... seems that my object is not sent correctly. I used a populate over the array, but as the profile is inside an object... it is not processed. Seems you were right.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help